# "How to show the value of differences between two line's datapoint in Line-plot ?"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, line-plot

I have made a line plot now I want to show the value of differences/gap between two lines in the line plot within the figure.

I am not getting it how to show the gap value between the two lines.

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

My result:

[image: My output result]

dataframe:
[image: dataframe image]

My code:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
df_MFgrade4.plot(figsize=(15,8), marker='o', color=('#E8743B', '#5bc0de'))
plt.xlabel("Year", fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel("Average Mathematics Scale Score", fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(df_grade4["Year"].astype(int), size=13)
plt.yticks(df1, size=13)
plt.legend(fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

Comment: [`fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) to get the fill between the lines. You can also use `matplotlib.pyplot.text` to add the labels you want. Since you didn't post any code here is a generic example to illustrate.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
ticks = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y1 = np.zeros((len(x)))
y2 = np.zeros((len(x)))
xmax = 0.0
imax = 0
for ii in range(len(x)):
    y1[ii] = 50 * ii - 5 * ii**2
    y2[ii] = 50 * ii - 7 * ii**2
    ticks[ii] = y1[ii]-y2[ii]
    if (y1[ii] < 0.0):
        xmax = x[ii]
        imax = ii
        break
ymax = max(y1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4), dpi=300)
plt.plot(x, y1, 'g:')
plt.plot(x, y2, 'b:')
plt.ylim([0, ymax*1.05])
plt.xlim([0, xmax])
plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='grey', alpha=0.3)
print imax
for ii in range(imax):
    plt.text(x[ii], ymax*0.01, ticks[ii])
plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib fill_between example plotting projectile motion]

The labels just above the `x` axis indicate the difference between the values at every point.

#### Edit

Since you are coming from a `pandas` `DataFrame`, in order to achieve the finer-grain control of the plot you need it may be necessary, or at least convenient, to convert the columns of that `DataFrame` to lists and plot using exactly the method above, e.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(font='Times New Roman')

d = {'Year'  : [1990, 1992, 1996, 2000, 2003, 2005, 2007, 2009, 2011,
                2013, 2015, 2017],
     'Male'  : [214, 221, 224, 227, 236, 239, 241, 241, 241, 242, 241, 241],
     'Female': [213, 219, 223, 224, 233, 237, 239, 239, 240, 241, 239, 239]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

male = df['Male'].tolist()
female = df['Female'].tolist()
year = df['Year'].tolist()
ymax = max(male)
ymin = min(female)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,10), dpi=300)

# ymin*0.99 should be changed according to the dataset
for ii in range(len(male)):
    plt.text(year[ii]-0.1, ymin*0.99, male[ii]-female[ii], size=16)

plt.plot(year, male, marker=".", color="#5bc0de")
plt.plot(year, female, marker=".", color="#E8743B")
plt.ylim([ymin*0.985, ymax*1.01])
plt.fill_between(year, male, female, color="grey", alpha=0.3)
plt.yticks(male, size=16)
plt.xticks(year, size=16)
plt.title("Matplotlib fill_between() and text() 
           from pandas.DataFrame example", fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image: Example using pandas DataFrame]

You may have to make adjustments to the position of the labels if you apply this to a different dataset.

Comment: I think William that he wants that difference to be shown as values like in the expected plot we are seeing just above x-axis.

Comment: @AmitAmola Yeah I realized that after posting.... thanks for the comment

Comment: William my man, it took me 45 mins to finally get it, just to see that you've already answered... hahaha... 

Nice work btw! And can't vote up coz daily limit reached... will do in the morning for sure.

Comment: @AmitAmola Thanks, sorry to scoop ya haha

Comment: I am just adding my code and data frame so that it will be clear for you to understand.

Comment: @AvijitSaha See the edited code for an example using your data

Comment: Thanks a lot @William Miller.

Comment: @AvijitSaha Be sure to accept if this answered your question correctly

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54065121/12201993

same answer as above, in case you encounter this problem -

> TypeError: alpha must be a float or None

when the packages get updated, then change the alpha in plt.fill_between to a float, eg:

`plt.fill_between(year, male, female, color="grey", alpha=0.3)`